# Cut power to a phone without a removable battery?

Tags: battery, system-freeze

Well just as the title says, if you have a phone without a removable battery (HTC One X) and it freezes while modding it, how do you cut the power if you can't pop out the battery?

I could see non removable batteries being a huge issue to phone modders like me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

HTC's solution to this issue is to "Press and hold the Power button for at least 10 seconds, and then release it. HTC One X will be shutdown and then boot again."

This is the only solution I would be able to see. If you require something more, then as a phone modder I would recommend you take apart the phone and manually disconnect the battery. This is rather risky unless you are confident in what you are doing. You may be able to refer to this page: http://htcpedia.com/news/HTC-One-X-How-To-Take-It-Apart.html for a tutorial on how to disassemble the unibody of the HTC one x.

The last safe option you have is to simply wait a day or so (since it is stuck on) until the battery drains completely. From there of course charge it up again and continue with whatever software modding you were doing.

Comment: Asus do this, too, for their tablets. Hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds and it does a hard-reboot.

Comment: Same for Samsung phones & tablets.

Answer (score 4):

It greatly depends on what conditions made your phone to freeze, but generally a long press (10 sec) on the power button might get your phone to reset itself. YMMV, though.

Answer (score 2):

Holding down (volume up+ volume down +power button) at the same time worked for my HTC desire 826 dual sim mobile(Android 5.0.2). not worked holding down power button for more than 10 seconds or even more.

Comment: Works for Samsung A3 (2016) in bootloop. However this combination makes the phone just restart (not power off). So I needed immediately after that press volume up + home + power to boot into recovery.

Answer (score 0):

On RAZR, it's hold the volume down button and the power for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Kyocera Hydro with an internal battery. Holding down the power button got it to power down and then immediately power back on. As though I told it to reset. I probably held the power button for a bit longer then 10 seconds but just keep holding it. It should do the trick. My phone is only partially rooted so I assume this trick would work for a fully rooted Kyocera Hydro or 1 with no administer permissions at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I can power down my frozen Galaxy Tab (with an unremoveable battery) by holding down the power button for more than 10 seconds. Before I found that out, I used to wait for the battery to drain overnight when the tablet had frozen.