# How to cut power to a already-switched-off phone without a removable battery

Tags: huawei, power-on

Note that I am already aware of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/cut-power-to-a-phone-without-a-removable-battery). But it can not solve my question because my phone is already switched off.

I have Huawei without removable battery that I would prefer to cut power to because I got quite some disinfectant on it when it was already switched off. How I can cut power to my phone completely when it is already switched off (without switching it on)?

Comment: watch disassembly video and disconnect battery

Comment: If you really make sure the phone is off then the answer is still the same: remove the battery. On modern device removing the battery of course is not that simple and requires appropriate tools and little bit of skill. For inspiration check if there is a video on e.g. iFixIt or YouTube how to disassemble the device.